# how to change css of CDetailView?

Tags: php, yii

1) how will I remove that alternating blue color of the CDetailView css ?
2) and let's say,based from the code below, How will I change the PositionTitle into `<h1>Position</h1 ?` 
3) how will I apply a different css class for each attribute ?

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
            'PositionTitle',
            'PositionSummary',
            'PositionDetails',
            'SkillsRequiredCompulsary',
            'SkillsRequiredNonCompulsary',
            'StartDate',
            'EndDate',
            'QualificationsRequiredCompulsary',
            'QualificationsRequiredNonCompulsary',
            'SalaryFrom',
            'SalaryTo',
            'SalaryPer',
            'Currency',
            'Benefits',
            'CompanySector',
            'PositionSector',
            'PositionLevel',
    ),
```

Answer (score 2):

read this [doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDetailView#attributes-detail),

there you can find that you can specify attributes as array'

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
            array('name'=>'PositionTitle','cssClass'=>'yourClass'),
            'PositionSummary',
            'PositionDetails',
            'SkillsRequiredCompulsary',
            'SkillsRequiredNonCompulsary',
            'StartDate',
            'EndDate',
            'QualificationsRequiredCompulsary',
            'QualificationsRequiredNonCompulsary',
            'SalaryFrom',
            'SalaryTo',
            'SalaryPer',
            'Currency',
            'Benefits',
            'CompanySector',
            'PositionSector',
            'PositionLevel',
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look [at the docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDetailView) you will see there's a cssFile parameter, which you can use to include a CSS file and override the styles that the widget provides by default.

You can see the HTML output generated by the widget into your page or open the class in order to know what styles you should define in your CSS.

Comment: what i did was, I added this `'cssFile' => Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl .'/css/profile.css',` and within that profile.css file, I pasted the styles.css codes from the assets folder of detailview, but still nothing happened when I refereshed the page after overriding the css stuff that I pasted

Comment: Have you checked with firebug that the CSS stylesheet you have defined is actually loading?